# How to solve "(Id: user.uid)" error in this file?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:twitter/models/users.dart';


class AuthService{
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  UserModel? _userFromFirebaseUSer(User user){
    return user != null ? UserModel(Id: user.uid) :null
  }

  Future SignIn(email,Password) async{
    try {
      User user= (await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: Password)) as User;
      _userFromFirebaseUSer(user);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future SignUp(email,Password) async{
    try {
      User user= (await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: Password)) as User;
      _userFromFirebaseUSer(user);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

in the users.dart file this is the code I have written. however, it gives me an error, and I am not able to solve, and it worked in the tutorial I was watching with no problems, so what is the problem here?

```
class UserModel{
  final String Id;

  UserModel(this.Id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem in your code. ( If you could place here the exception you are getting it will be helpful ) but I see two issues that could cause some error.

1. Missing semicolon at the end of the return statement on the third line of your AuthService class
2. Try to always name your class attributes with the first letter on lower camel case -> final String Id; it may compile but some languages are not so free about that.